# HikariPool Failed to validate connection

Tags: java, postgresql, event-sourcing, hikaricp, axon

I'm using [Axon Framework](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/) as my event sourcing framework, the only axon config I have in place is:

> axon.saga.integrateAndShelve.threadCount = 2
>
> axon.saga.integrateAndShelve.segmentCount = 6

For the data source of my Event Store, I use the following config:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://{url}
>
> spring.datasource.username=user
>
> spring.datasource.password=pass
>
> spring.datasource.maxActive=200 ( had to add this because of this recurrent error Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection)
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
>
> spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

And just as the title mentioned, I'm getting this error thrown in the logs, not sure if it skipped writing an event since I didn't get any other logs (no failure to write, no retries) but it got me worried

> HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7e44c5d8 (This connection has been
> closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

Edit: Adding some relevant build.gradle info

```
annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
compile "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.4.RELEASE"
compile('org.postgresql:postgresql')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
compile("org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.0.3") {
    exclude group: 'org.axonframework', module: 'axon-server-connector'
}

testCompile "org.axonframework:axon-test:4.1"
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
```

Comment: Hi @bleh10, are you sure this is Axon related? If I were you, I would investigate more on Hikari config checking their [github page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) and also enabling their powerful `leakDetectionThreshold`. It should give you some insight of where the problem might be. Other than that, it would be beneficial to see at least your `pom.xml` and `application.properties` to help on the matter. Checking your DAO/Repository would help as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm suspecting it's an axon related issue because my config (gradle or app.prop) doesnt setup/configure hikari so I assumed it's something axon is taking care of, the axon config and event store config are the related part to my app.propreties, will update my gradle build if you think its relevant

Comment: Guessing this lies with Spring Boot's auto config somewhere, but not sure in which portion to be honest... Axon's auto config doesn't do anything specific when it comes to connection pools and such; it only validates that there's JPA on the classpath by requiring an existing `EntityManagerFactory` bean.